# Data encryption for the resources in android

Tags: android, android-assets

I am using database files and some text files which I have put in the Assets folder. When any user downloads my APK file and extracts it, he will get my resources from the assets folder easily.

How can I encrypt all my resources so that if anyone gets my resources, he can't use it?

Comment: You may select level of encryption on basis of your application usability. But may use internal Java encryption classes

Comment: You can use AES encryption java class to encrypt and decrypt your resources

Comment: http://javapapers.com/java/java-symmetric-aes-encryption-decryption-using-jce/

Comment: Consider how effective this would be. Whatever the app can do, an attacker can do as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the asset file is already encrypted, Java's [CipherInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html) to decrypt content of the asset file would help your need

```
// Cipher that holds algorithm (E.g. AES)
Cipher cipher = getCipherProbablyAES();


// Get input stream to that file. Handle IOException on your own
InputStream assetFile = getAssets().open("myEncrypted.txt");
CipherInputStream cipherIS = CipherInputStream(assetFile, cipher);
```